# It's Santa Time!

Tags: discussion, fun, gravatar

Let's do this. What with the DramaLlama being out in full force, I think it's time to take a breather and bring the funny back. To wit: I propose the Santification of your gravatars till after the new year. Some of us have already gotten started. You can use the image as your baseline.

[image]

or

[image]

Now get crackin!

Also, for your [general amusement](http://elfyourself.jibjab.com/view/wHdP2omOHqquiLeP?cmpid=ey_url) and straight from New York [your sysadmins](http://elfyourself.jibjab.com/view/iOPRhpUhLW12Pcw6)

**Boxing Day update** (I didn't think it was worth starting a new thread): now that Christmas is over and New Year's is up next, if anyone wants to switch to a party hat, this one is nice and shiny:

[image]

Comment: All regulars and high-ish rep users should be required to have hats in chat.  And in answers.

Comment: e.g. http://serverfault.com/questions/341935/hdd-misbehavior-fs-ok-but-files-are-corrupt

Comment: @Ward Upon penalty of being spit on by the aforementioned BabyMamaBramahSlamaFujiyamaDramaLlama

Comment: I wish I could upvote my own post just because of the dancing elves

Comment: I just watched that elf thing. I'm scarred for life now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]

Answer (score 17):

I don't normally go for this kind of nonsense, being more of a Grinch than a Santa, but what the heck.
[image]

The beard has grown back a bit since this was taken.

Comment: Hey hey welcome to the club ;) Now you're one of the cool kids!

Comment: Well, you *would* be one of the cool kids if you'd activate this pic as your Gravatar.

Comment: Golly gosh, I've never been a cool kid before.

Answer (score 16):

[image]

Comment: Boba Fett and Darth Vader in vintage suits and santa hats. I think I can die now.

Answer (score 14):

We're still waiting for:

[image: ewwhite]

and

[image: jeff attwood aka coding horror]

Answer (score 13):

[image: Snow Angel that Appeared in my Front Lawn Last Winter]

Comment: A good attempt, sir. And yet your gravatar remains shockingly boring

Comment: There you go, sir. I hope that makes you happy! :D

Comment: It does! Welcome to the club!

Answer (score 13):

Mah Turn.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

The Santification has started. I believe that shortly our Santorium will be complete.

[image]

Comment: You're a dirty, dirty man

Comment: He's a Lumberjack and he's ok!
He works all night and he sleeps all day!

Comment: "works", "night", "sleeps", "day"

Answer (score 12):

I'm in the spirit.

[image: I'm a tree]

Answer (score 12):

Can't really decide. Either something remotely similar to my usually avatar:

[image]

or the alternative:

[image]

Comment: I like the alternative

Answer (score 11):

For your consideration, I offer up two:
[image: avatar-santa]
[image: choppertar-santa]

Comment: It's this sort of snowflake escalation that leads to trouble...

Answer (score 11):

[image: Thought I'd revive an old favourite]

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Comment: You've gotta get Kenny to do his, too.

Comment: Will do :). I'll send him a text :)

Comment: Done, fun initiative!

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Answer (score 11):

### Ho ho ho!

[image: Stefan "Santa" Plattner]

*"This year **nobody** gets what they want."*

Answer (score 11):

How's this;

[image]

Comment: A new beard *and* mistletoe?! Paddington had better watch out!

Comment: He's a dirty, dirty bear.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

Answer (score 10):

[image]

Answer (score 10):

[image]

Answer (score 10):

(Courtesy of Iain)

[image]

Comment: No Christmas sock?

Answer (score 10):

[image]

Answer (score 10):

[image]

*kitteh head bonk of approval*

Answer (score 10):

My father *is* Santa. [No joke](https://twitter.com/#!/Kriskringlenoel).

Three-minutes in paint.net:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

[image]

Comment: This is *fantastic*. Have you done the cat's ass + lipstick test?

Comment: Uuuh... no... I have not

Answer (score 10):

[image: Spiff Santa Hat]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Chris s]

Answer (score 10):

Hat.
[image]

Comment: Good man. Wouldn't want to be caught running around under-dressed, now would we? It's a bold new future we march towards, young man!

Answer (score 10):

[image]

Yes, that's right, I took a photo of myself actually wearing a hat. A silly hat.

Comment: Well, I think silly is what it's all about, so you've done well.

Answer (score 10):

Normal:

[image: Christmas avatar]

A variation:

[image: Christmas lolcat]

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37597/what-kind-of-computer-is-being-used-in-workin-on-ur-problemz and http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/workin-on-ur-problemz/

Answer (score 9):

[image: http://i.imgur.com/xcj80.jpg]

And if you want the tree... 
[image: Tree]

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if I want to go with the generated image + hat:

[image]

Or something pony-related:

[image]

Comment: *Mr Burns voice* Yeeeesssss, it's all coming together quite nicely now...

Comment: Also, pony related. Like that was a hard choice.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few other Santa-hat-wearing Gravatars kicking around, e.g. this one from [Aaronut](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/41/aaronut), a mod on Cooking.SE and sometimes-contributor to SF:

[image: Aaronut gravatar]

Hobodave is another mod on Cooking.SE who shows up on SF every now and then, so I asked him to add a hat to his gravatar as well.

Comment: I've seen a few other SF regulars with them as well, they just haven't seen fit to update here

Answer (score 5):

Seeing as how cat pictures appear to be popular around here...

This is how our cat has decided to spend the evenings lately, snuggled up between me and my computer.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image: My husband and I, celebrating Christmas. Uhum.]

Comment: I'm not a SF user but found it cool to share my gravatar here. I can delete it if it's not appropriate or something.

Comment: SE accounts are linked magically, you *are* an SF user now. :)

Comment: @jscott, you forgot to add the evil "muahahahahaha" after.

Answer (score 4):

(shameless bump)

Santa time again!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]