# Update your Gravatars in repsonse to SOPA/PIPA?

Tags: discussion

Since we had a community effort to wear [Santa Hats](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2394/its-santa-time), I don't feel too bad about posting this. I think several (most? almost all?) of us agree on the pending SOPA / PIPA legislation.

Today is SOPA Blackout day, and I changed my gravatar last night (and might keep it that way for a while longer than 24 hours...).

Will you?

Comment: I approve this message

Comment: Provide some banners/example images, and I'll get right on that.

Comment: You can do a search for "stop sopa avatars" and there's plenty of goodies

Comment: Wouldn't it be funny if Gravatar blacked out :)

Comment: @TylerShads - no, it wouldn't

Comment: Christmas is one thing. Local politics is something else altogether.

Answer (score 3):

Done

Link to the image I used: http://www.blackoutsopa.org/static/templates/stopsopa_all_black.png

Answer (score 3):

I've done mine as well. Image from http://secularnewsdaily.s3.amazonaws.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/StopSOPA_NewLogo_SOPA_PIPA.jpg

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a handy overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPJ7B.png) (the one I used for my gravatar, should you choose to use it.

Answer (score 2):

As a newbie I considered posting a "question" regarding this until I figured out the right part of the site to go.

For those not familiar with xkcd I thought I would post this:

[image: SOPA]

(If you edit the colours it ends up looking a bit more like this):

[image: Don't screw with DNS]

Edit: I tried to embed the pictures via bbcode or whatever this forum uses but it turned out to be way too past beer o clock :(

Edit (after even more beer): Apparently over 75k websites participated:
http://sopastrike.com/on-strike/

Comment: **[SF] IS NOT A FORUM!** It's not bbcode. [SE] are Q&A sites and use a broken version of [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/).

Comment: @ChrisS +1 for emphasizing brokenness.